# Does jQuery always iterate through DOMs in order in which they are found in the code?

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

Say, for example, I have a sortable list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What I want to know is, if I make a jQuery call such as the following:

`$.each($('li'), function(key, item) {...});`

Can I expect jQuery to go through the entries from top to bottom? I've run a few tests, and tried rearranging items dynamically using jQueryUI, and so far, it seems to always run in order. But can this always be expected? Or is it dumb luck that I've not run into anything so far to make me think otherwise...?

Comment: It *should*. Then again, browsers always manage to insert odd bugs...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *"Can I expect jQuery to go through the entries from top to bottom?"*

Yes. They are iterated by numeric index from `0` to `length - 1`.

The elements will always be returned in the order that they appear in the DOM.

> *"I've run a few tests, and tried rearranging items dynamically..."*

It doesn't give consideration to CSS positioning if that's what you mean. If you're changing their actual location in the DOM, then you'd only see the updates if you re-select them from the DOM.

Comment: It would seem jQueryIU scrollable actually repositions the DOMs in the document. The ideal end result is not having to assign an actual sort attribute and trust jQuery with the correct order after the user sorts the DOMs

Comment: @KyleMacey I've relied on jquery returning them in the proper order for several of my applications without having any issues.

Comment: @KyleMacey: Did you mean sortable instead of scrollable?

Comment: @gdoron: That's a fair point. I can't find any such guarantee in the docs. Also, some traversal methods return a different order by design, like `.prevAll()`, which returns elements in reverse document order, starting with the closest to the targeted element.

Comment: @gdoron - Since jQuery 1.3.2, all jquery methods return elements in document order. http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2 However this isn't true for `.prevAll()` and `.prevUntil()`, as noted in the docs.

Comment: @KevinB: From the docs... *"...the elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling."* so it's the intended behavior. With respect to document order, I personally wouldn't call it official until it made its way into the official API docs. But that's me. ;)

Comment: Interesting, though, there is a method that will return a collection back to document order for anyone interested in that: `$("ul > li:last").prevUntil(":first").unique()`

Comment: @KevinB: Almost. That's a utility method of `jQuery`, so you'd need to send the collection as an argument... `$.unique($("ul > li:last").prevUntil(":first"))`

Answer (score 4):

It didn't use to, but since [jQuery 1.3.2](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3.2) selectors return elements in the order in which they are found in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

There is no where in the docs that promise this behavior, but this the way it's currently implemented.

That said, I can't see a reason why would they change this behavior.

Comment: They mention the change in the 1.3.2 release notes, I'm not sure if that's enough to give you a warm fuzzy but they intend to be compliant with the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) which specifies to return elements in the DOM order.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino Well played.

Comment: +1 fair point. They should firm this up in the docs if it's their intention.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino. As I said since version `1.3.2` this is the behavior, but they didn't promise it will "last for ever"