# How to iterate from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery .each() backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

With Jquery, how can I iterate from bottom to top ?

For example, I have this list:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get item 3, then item 2 and then item 1...

Comment: I believe this is similar to:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182654/does-jquery-always-iterate-through-doms-in-order-in-which-they-are-found-in-the

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could to it like this:

```
$($("li")
        .get()
        .reverse())
        .each(function() {
         // some code

         });
```